# Black Background When Adding an Image in Xcode Project

Tags: xcode, swift, image, project

Whenever I add an image in my Project, no matter what the extention of the image is, the background in the simulator gets black!!!!!
Anyone knows  why? And how can I solve this?

[image]

Comment: have you set background color of the imageView... try changing background color of imageView to something else

Comment: Yes, It did work after I changed the background color. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thing is your `image` is smaller then `imageView`, either set background color to any other or set it to clear color (if you want to make it clear).